# Trying to add custom object to ArrayList. Output is gibberish

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Card {

  int number;
  String suit;

  public Card(int number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] suit = {
      "Clubs",
      "Diamonds",
      "Spades",
      "Hearts"
    };

    ArrayList<Card> deckOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>(52);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

        deckOfCards.add(i+1, suit[j]);
      }
    }


    System.out.println(deckOfCards);
  }
}
```

I'm new to methods and we need to create a deck of cards where cards are methods not a string or a int etc (the method deck is suppose to be the cards). Not 100% sure what part I'm doing wrong but I keep getting error:

```
Card.java:27: error: no suitable method found for add(int,String)
        deckOfCards.add(i+1, suit[j]);
                   ^
    method List.add(int,Card) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Card)
    method AbstractList.add(int,Card) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Card)
    method ArrayList.add(int,Card) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Card)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
Michaels-MacBook-Air-2:Computer Science michaelzakariaie$
```

Any tips/help greatly appreciated, I'm pretty sure its a simple error and I'm just blanking out

Edit: Figured out to change syntax when adding the card but the output is giberish when I run it, anyone know how to fix that?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Card {

  int number;
  String suit;

  public Card(int number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] suit = {
      "Clubs",
      "Diamonds",
      "Spades",
      "Hearts"
    };

    ArrayList<Card> deckOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>(52);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

        deckOfCards.add(new Card (i+1, suit[j]));
      }
    }

    //  deckOfCards.add(new Card (1, "hi"));

    System.out.println(deckOfCards);
  }
}
```

new code^

Thanks

Comment: As the error tells you, you are trying to insert a _String_ object, in an ArrayList of _Card_ objects.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
deckOfCards.add(i+1, suit[j]);
```

To this:

```
deckOfCards.add(new Card(i+1, suit[j]));
```

Or this:

```
Card current = new Card(i+1, suit[j]);
deckOfCards.add(current);
```

I would probably do the later because putting each action on its own line (i.e. creating the card and then add it) is easier to read.  It's also easier to debug--in the first option, if you have an error on that line you can't be sure whether it's related to creating the card or adding it.

Comment: you should explain the difference to OP

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

Add an actual `Card` object to the `ArrayList<Card>` instead of a String.

```
deckOfCards.add(new Card(i+1, suit[j]));
```

---

**Problem 2**

> The output is gibberish

You need to implement a `toString` method for `Card`

```
public class Card {

    int number;
    String suit;

    public Card(int number, String suit) {
        this.number = number;
        this.suit = suit;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
                "number=" + number +
                ", suit='" + suit + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deckOfCards.add(i+1, suit[j]);// Change this to ....

deckOfCards.add(i+1, new Card(i+1,suit[j]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A Card cannot be a method. Methods are actions and Classes are nouns.

In your example you have a Card class. Instantiate a card and add it to the array list.

```
Card card = new Card(i+1, suit[j])
```

ArrayList uses generics represented with the angle brackets <>. The generic type specifies it holds objects of type Card. You cannot insert Object of type String into that list.